# Z-index input form

Tags: html, z-index

I have this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmF4S/3/

```
<div style="float: left; position: relative;">
<input type="text" placeholder="Search..." style="float: left; border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px; padding: 2px 4px; margin-top: 6px; margin-left: 8px; border: 1px solid rgb(143, 241, 255); height: 22px; font-size: 14px; font-family: Arial; width: 200px;" name="password" id="password">
<div style="background-color: red; left: 5px; right: 9939px; top: 30px; position: absolute; width: 100px; padding: 50px">
s
</div>
</div>
```

I would the red box to be overwritten from the input form (e.g. input form is over the red box, that is partially hidden from the input form), however z-indexes won't work. What could i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please try this : If i understand you....

http://jsfiddle.net/cmF4S/19/

Answer (score 0):

i'm not sure i understand you. but you need the red box behind the input field?
else here is your solution:

http://jsfiddle.net/cmF4S/12/

greets,
stefan